# Spamassassin not respecting my blacklist

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I've tried putting my `blacklist_from` and `whitelist_from` lines in `~/.spamassassin/user_prefs` and in `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`, but they appear to be ignored.

This is from postfix's `master.cf`:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
   -o content_filter=spamassassin

spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=debian-spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

I copied these from some guide I found on Google, and honestly, I don't know why `spamc` is piping the mail to sendmail.

I'm not sure what I else I should provide, and I don't want to post a huge question pasting all my config files. Just ask and I'll edit my question.

Comment: Hi, did you resolved it yet? If yes, it would be great if you share it via the answer section. if not, can you edit the post and mentioned the OS when the problem happens...?